# Bolted connection moment resistance

Tags: structural-engineering, steel

I'm reading the Steel Construction Institute book Moment-resisting joints to Eurocode 3.

In chapter 2, bolted beam to column connections using end plates are covered. For a connection with multiple bolt rows, a following scheme is given to calculate the resistance of a single row:

[image]

The idea is, that for a connection such as this:

[image]

we first calculate the tension resistance of the topmost row (1). Then we calculate the resistance of row 2. Then we calculate the resistance of rows 1 and 2 together as part of a group, and subtract the resistance of bolt row 1 alone. The resistance of row 2 is then the lesser value of either the row alone, or the amount of resistance that row 2 *adds* to the group of rows formed by rows 1 and 2.

Similarly for the row 3: the resistance of row 3 is the lesser of either the resistance of the row alone, the amount of resistance the row adds to the group formed by rows 2 and 3, or the amount of resistance that the row adds to the group formed by all the rows together.

**Why is this scheme used to calculate the resistance of a row?** Why don't we simply calculate only the resistance of the row alone, as well as the resistance of all the groups the row belongs to? Why do we only consider the amount of resistance the row *adds* to a particular group?

Comment: The stress flow in a moment connection is a complicated matter which is not possible to understand without resorting to the research paper that has come up with the design method and adopted by the code. You shall check into the commentary on the code and the included references for information.

Comment: @r13 I cannot find references to research in Eurocode, do you know where to look for them?

Comment: On P5 of the linked article, there is a detailed procedure for the stiffened end-plate moment connection, which might shed some light. https://www.steelconstruction.info/images/5/5d/SCI_P398.pdf

Comment: Also note, there are detailed examples of endplate connections that could provide clues to the reasoning.

Comment: Basically, the code considers different/potential modes of bolt failure in the plastic state. A complicated matter simplified after many research works, which should be the direction of your search for answers. Good luck.

Comment: @r13 Ok, thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Euro Code is written based on the Limit State Design and considers plastic (nonlinear) deformation when the structure fails. The design of the endplate moment connection is complicated by the fact that, on top of the bolts, there are quite a few factors that can contribute to the failure - column flanges and web; beam flanges and web; the size, thickness, and configuration of the bolt holes. Each, or a combination, of the above, will have influences on the stress in the bolt, and resulting in different failure "modes". Therefore, the code has devised an enveloped criteria (as written in the OP) in an effort to find the weakest combination (mode), which will then be the ultimate design load for the concern of safety.

Below is an illustration of the influences of the different failure modes on bolt row 2.

[image]